# Show related posts' categories in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to also display the category of a related post, below one article.

I am using Newsmag theme.

The code that builds my related posts is this:

```
class td_module {

    var $post;
    var $title_attribute;
    var $title;
    var $href;
    var $td_review; //review meta
    var $category;

    //constructor

    function __construct($post) {
        //this filter is used by td_unique_posts.php - to add unique posts to the array for the datasource

        apply_filters("td_wp_boost_new_module", $post);
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->title = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $this->title_attribute = esc_attr(strip_tags($this->title));
        $this->href = esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID));
        $this->category = '';

        if (has_post_thumbnail($this->post->ID)) {
            $this->post_has_thumb = true;
        } else {
            $this->post_has_thumb = false;
        }

        //get the review metadata
        $this->td_review = get_post_meta($this->post->ID, 'td_review', true);
    }
```

and the part that displays the related articles is this:

```
$buffy .= '<div class="td-module-thumb">';

                if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
                    $buffy .= '<a class="td-admin-edit" href="' . get_edit_post_link($this->post->ID) . '">edit</a>';
                }

                $buffy .='<a href="' . $this->href . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . $this->title_attribute . '">';

                    $buffy .= '<img width="' . $td_temp_image_url[1] . '" height="' . $td_temp_image_url[2] . '" itemprop="image" class="entry-thumb" src="' . $td_temp_image_url[0] . '" ' . $attachment_alt . $attachment_title . '/>';

                       $buffy .= '<span class="td-module-thumb-category">'.$this->category.'</span>';
....................................
```

`$this->category` was added by me. I am trying to get the data from wp_terms table and display the categories of each of the related posts.
I am new to WordPress(actually, this is the first time I touch WordPress code).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with your existing code:

```
$buffy .= '<div class="td-module-thumb">';
    $related_category = get_the_category($this->post->ID);

    if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        $buffy .= '<a class="td-admin-edit" href="' . get_edit_post_link($this->post->ID) . '">edit</a>';
    }

    $buffy .='<a href="' . $this->href . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . $this->title_attribute . '">';

        $buffy .= '<img width="' . $td_temp_image_url[1] . '" height="' . $td_temp_image_url[2] . '" itemprop="image" class="entry-thumb" src="' . $td_temp_image_url[0] . '" ' . $attachment_alt . $attachment_title . '/>';

           $buffy .= '<span class="td-module-thumb-category">'.$related_category[0]->cat_name.'</span>';
```

Or if you need the category to be a link use:

```
$buffy .= '<div class="td-module-thumb">';
    $related_category = get_the_category($this->post->ID);

    if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        $buffy .= '<a class="td-admin-edit" href="' . get_edit_post_link($this->post->ID) . '">edit</a>';
    }

    $buffy .='<a href="' . $this->href . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . $this->title_attribute . '">';

        $buffy .= '<img width="' . $td_temp_image_url[1] . '" height="' . $td_temp_image_url[2] . '" itemprop="image" class="entry-thumb" src="' . $td_temp_image_url[0] . '" ' . $attachment_alt . $attachment_title . '/>';

           $buffy .= '<span class="td-module-thumb-category"><a href="'.get_category_link($related_category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$related_category[0]->cat_name.'</a></span>';
```

You will probably want to move `$related_category = get_the_category($this->post->ID);` to where you have `$this->category = '';` in your first pasted code segment